# How to get Kafka log size efficiently?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am building a UI where I want to display the log size of a kafka topic and how much each consumer has read. I can read the consumer offsets from zookeeper. What would be the efficient way to get the log size of a topic. I might need to update the details say every 10 seconds. 
I can get the log size from jmx or using a simple consumer and latest offset time. Is this the best available options or Is there any other efficient option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any direct mechanism to find out that. 
But to find out the total size of data for a given partition, you can go to file system based on *logs.dir* configured in your *server.properties* and read each partition directory size.

To find out consumer off-set read size, may be you need calculate approximate number based on message-size configured and offset records.

Still, this does not give exact sizes that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Kakka exposes mbeans through which I can read the log size. If I read say every 10 or 5 seconds , would it affect the performance?

Comment: did you figure out how to get the log size from the mbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [KafkaOffsetMonitor](https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor) for an easy way to see graphs of each consumer's offset, log size, and lag.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Any idea how the log size is calculated/obtained in kafkaoffsetmonitor?